# Is it possible to use user defined aggregates (clr) with window functions (over)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlclr, window-functions

Is it possible to use user defined aggregates (clr) with window functions (over) ?

Can't find the answer in the documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190678.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right that it's tricky to find anything in the documentation. But searching the Connect website, I managed to find this [gem](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/586867/user-defined-ranking-functions):

> Today, you can use CLR aggregates with OVER clause and PARTITION BY just like regular aggregate functions. Once we have support for window functions...

Which was a response from Microsoft.

---

However, searching on the Connect site was what I did whilst I was waiting for my aged machine to create a new database project and create this aggregate:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

[Serializable]
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined,MaxByteSize = 2000)]
public struct SqlAggregate1 : IBinarySerialize
{
    private SqlString last;
    public void Init()
    {
        // Ignore
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlString Value)
    {
        last = Value;
    }

    public void Merge (SqlAggregate1 Group)
    {
        // Ignore
    }

    public SqlString Terminate ()
    {
        // Put your code here
        return last;
    }

    public void Read(BinaryReader r)
    {
        last = new SqlString(r.ReadString());
    }

    public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
    {
        w.Write(last.ToString());
    }
}
```

And then run this script:

```
select dbo.SqlAggregate1(Column2) OVER (PARTITION BY Column1)
from (select 1,'abc' union all select 1,'def' union all
      select 2,'ghi' union all select 2,'jkl') as t(Column1,Column2)
```

Which produces:

```
------------
abc
abc
ghi
ghi
```

Which is a long way to say - you could have easily discovered the answer for yourself just by **trying** it.

Comment: But neither `ORDER BY` nor `ROWS` nor `RANK` seems to be supported within the `OVER` clause. That just gives a syntax error.

Comment: @Jens - all that the MS connect item promises is `PARTITION BY`. And if you consider how CLR aggregates are defined (especially `Merge`) you'll realise that, in their current form, they cannot support those other parts (we lose ordering information)

Comment: I encourage people to actually vote on the [Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/586867/user-defined-ranking-functions) so Microsoft is more likely to actually implement this some day.

Comment: This example show why it make no sense without the option of ordering. Your result assume specific order but in fact you might get different result in different execution since you have no column which used for order by and the function does not do any ordering. I would NOT use this function or approach until there will be support for SQLCLR windows function with ORDER BY and option to configure the windows