# Is there an easy way to group interpolated start/finish dates in SQL?

Tags: sql

So basically, let's say we have a list of items that have start and finish dates. Something like this:

```
| Name   | Start     | Finish   |
---------------------------------
| Item 1 | Jan 1     | Jan 4    |
| Item 2 | Jan 3     | Jan 5    |
| Item 3 | Jan 4     | Jan 7    |

| Item 4 | Jan 10    | Jan 14   |

| Item 5 | Jan 15    | Jan 17   |
| Item 6 | Jan 17    | Jan 20   |

| Item 7 | Jan 25    | Jan 27   |
| Item 8 | Jan 26    | Jan 26   |
| Item 9 | Jan 27    | Jan 30   |
```

I basically need to get the dates for the groupings where items are in a group if its start date is between lowest start date and highest finish date for other members of the group, as shown above. Jan 1-7, Jan 10-14, Jan 15-20, and Jan 25-30. Is there any simpler way to do this in SQL than simply brute forcing it?

Thanks!

Comment: _Is there an **easy way** to group..._ What ways have you tried? Show code!

Comment: Brute forcing. Just iterating through the rows and adding them one by one

Comment: The question is not all to clear, LargeCrimsonFish, But the data seems to save you. What you seem to be after is to group together all items that were active (between start and finish) between periods of no activity . Is that right?

Comment: Right, that's exactly correct. I've been running nested while loops but that doesn't seem efficient, so i was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do so. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after is often called *sessionization* in, for example, clickstream analysis disciplines: We are grouping clicks together, by the same user on the same website, with less than 30 minutes inactivity between clicks, to analyse behaviours within such *sessions* .

Let me give you the quick answer - but it only works in Vertica, using the CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT analytic function:

https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/TimeSeries/CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENTAnalytic.htm

```
WITH
-- input data
foo(name,start,finish) AS (
          SELECT 'Item 1',DATE '2017-01-01',DATE '2017-01-04'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 2',DATE '2017-01-03',DATE '2017-01-05'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 3',DATE '2017-01-04',DATE '2017-01-07'

UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 4',DATE '2017-01-10',DATE '2017-01-14'

UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 5',DATE '2017-01-15',DATE '2017-01-17'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 6',DATE '2017-01-17',DATE '2017-01-20'

UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 7',DATE '2017-01-25',DATE '2017-01-27'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 8',DATE '2017-01-26',DATE '2017-01-26'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Item 9',DATE '2017-01-27',DATE '2017-01-30'
)

SELECT
  CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(start::TIMESTAMP > LAG(finish::TIMESTAMP))
OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY start) AS grp_id
, *
FROM foo;
```

The result is an increment by 1, starting from 0 and reset to 0 every time the PARTITION BY value changes (which is constant here), every time the expression between parentheses evaluates to TRUE:

```
grp_id|name  |start     |finish
     0|Item 1|2017-01-01|2017-01-04
     0|Item 2|2017-01-03|2017-01-05
     0|Item 3|2017-01-04|2017-01-07
     1|Item 4|2017-01-10|2017-01-14
     2|Item 5|2017-01-15|2017-01-17
     2|Item 6|2017-01-17|2017-01-20
     3|Item 7|2017-01-25|2017-01-27
     3|Item 8|2017-01-26|2017-01-26
     4|Item 9|2017-01-27|2017-01-30
```

Now. Does your database platform support generic Analytic functions, or does it not, as, for example, MySQL? Depending on your answer, I will rewrite this based on OLAP functions or based on correlated subselects.

But either way, this will take more time ....

Happy playing -

Marco the Sane

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you so much! Unfortunately I'm using the standard MS 2008 SQL Sever Management Studio so i'm not sure if your example will work yet, but knowing what the technique is called (sessionization) simplifies it a great deal. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, `CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT` is the most elegant solution, but since SQL does not support this natively, it can be done like this (preferred CTEs over subqueries).

```
;WITH DatesWithLag AS (
    SELECT 
      StartDate 
    , StopDate 
    , LAG(StopDate) OVER (ORDER BY StartDate) AS PrevStop 
    , DATEDIFF( 
         day 
      , LAG(StopDate) OVER (ORDER BY StartDate) 
      , StartDate 
      ) AS DayDiff
    FROM Dates
), 
Cond1 AS (
    SELECT 
      StartDate 
    , StopDate 
    , DayDiff 
    , (CASE WHEN DayDiff > 0 THEN 1 END) Change
    FROM DatesWithLag
),
Cond2 AS (
    SELECT 
      StartDate 
    , StopDate 
    , COUNT(Change) OVER ( 
        ORDER BY StartDate  
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
      ) Grp     --  
    FROM Cond1
)
SELECT Cond1.* 
     , Cond2.Grp 
FROM Cond1
    JOIN Cond2 ON Cond2.StartDate = Cond1.StartDate
ORDER BY Cond1.StartDate
GO
```

Another option is to implement `CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT` as a [CLR function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22353171/2780791)

Comment: Damn I really wish I could mark two answers as accepted :(. Thanks for the help, really taught me a lot today. I ended up doing some while loops before reading this answer.

Comment: My compliments, Alexei. My promised OLAP based solution would also have contained two additional Global Table expressions with very much the same content - I would have put all columns from your `Cond1` into `Cond2`, which is selecting from `Cond1` only anyway, to avoid the join.  But, in general, you saved me some homework ...