# Specify order that CollectionAggregate uses

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, geometry, concatenation, geospatial

I am enforcing the order in which geometry is contained in the `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` by concatenating the wkt and using `STUFF` with an `ORDER BY`

(I am using SQL Server 2016, otherwise I'd use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))

```
DECLARE @OrderedGeometryList TABLE  
(  
    [GroupId] INT,
    [Geometry] GEOMETRY,
    [Order] INT
)  


INSERT @OrderedGeometryList
VALUES 
     (1, 'LINESTRING(3 3, 4 4)', 3)
    ,(1, 'LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1)', 1)
    ,(1, 'LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2)', 2)
    ,(2, 'POINT(35453 141)', 2)
    ,(2, 'MULTILINESTRING((0 0, 1 1),(2 2, 3 3))', 1)
```

Then

```
;WITH Grouped AS (
    SELECT 
        [GroupId]
        ,Geometry::STGeomCollFromText(
            'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(' + 
                STUFF((
                    SELECT ',' + [Geometry].ToString()
                    FROM @OrderedGeometryList t2
                    WHERE t1.[GroupId] = t2.[GroupId] 
                    ORDER BY [Order]
                    FOR XML PATH ('')
                ), 1, 1, '')
            + ')', MAX([Geometry].STSrid)
        ) as [Geometry]
    FROM @OrderedGeometryList t1
    GROUP BY [GroupId]
)


SELECT GroupId, Geometry.ToString() as WKT
FROM Grouped
```

Produces:

```
GroupId WKT
1   GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1), LINESTRING (1 1, 2 2), LINESTRING (3 3, 4 4))
2   GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 1 1), (2 2, 3 3)), POINT (35453 141))
```

Notice how the collection order (left to right) follows the order specified in the table. This is the effect I am after but I am curious if there is a cleaner way to do this.

I considered writing my own CLR aggregate and then use `OVER()` with `ORDER BY` but it seems this is not supported [Is it possible to use user defined aggregates (clr) with window functions (over)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352026/is-it-possible-to-use-user-defined-aggregates-clr-with-window-functions-over)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OFFSET` at subquery for order the rows.

```
SELECT Geometry::CollectionAggregate([Geometry]).ToString() 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM @OrderedGeometryList ORDER BY [GroupId], [Order] OFFSET 0 ROWS) T
GROUP BY [GroupId]
```

Result:

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1), LINESTRING (1 1, 2 2), LINESTRING (3 3, 4 4))
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 1 1), (2 2, 3 3)), POINT (35453 141))
```

Comment: This is pretty ingenious. My only word of warning for others who come across this solution is that your WHERE statement needs to be in the subquery to be performant. If you try to add a WHERE statement on the outside query and/or try to wrap this into a view it will do the ORDER BY first and foremost