# Creating an exponential average

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr

I've been searching across documentation and internet, but it seems there's nothing about.

In SQL SERVER we have a really powerful function which is the windows frame. I can have something like this

```
SELECT
     [YearMonth]
    ,[OrderQuantity]
    ,[RunningTotal] = SUM([OrderQuantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Year]
                                                ORDER BY [YearMonth]
                                                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM [CTE_source]
ORDER BY [YearMonth];
```

In the OVER clause with the keyword ROWS I can filter the rows to apply my aggregate function.

With c#, according to documentation a can create a user defined aggregate function, but nowhere is there something window frame. Does someome have any idea or doc I could read? I would like to create an exponential average.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use user defined aggregates (clr) with window functions (over)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22352026/2029983)

Comment: *"I would like to create an explonential average."*  This is what your question should be about, not creating user defined aggregates.  Provide some sample data and the desired output, demonstrate what you have tried to do to achieve that output and where you are having difficulties

Comment: @iamdave Weel, first forgive my english, it is far from being perfect. My question was general, because, now I need to create an explonential average, but if where a way I would apply to other problems. It would be quite more efficent the cycling records.

Comment: @Larnu first of all, thanks. I didn't find that question with search. IT answers partially. I mean, it says the OVER works. But in the comment the sey that the part ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW doesn't work. No window frames. The thing I need for an exponential average.

Comment: By the way I know how to create an exponential average using cycles or a little of programming, but the window frames are more efficent if they would usable. I'm serching a more efficent way.

Comment: If you could just add your source data and your desired output from that data we would be able to help you.  Being 'general' does not really work in this Q&A format, as we don't know enough about your situation to provide an equally general answer.  If you give us your data and desired output however, we can help you find a solution to do that.